# Prove that every group (V, $*$, I) satisfies I^-1 = I

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that every group (V, $*$, I) satisfies I$^-$$^1$ = I.

According to my book, the solution is:

Take the definition of x$^-$$^1$: x $*$ x$^-$$^1$ = I $\land$ x$^-$$^1$ $*$ x = I

Then, by using the definition of the identity element of $*$ (which is x $*$ I = x $\land$ I $*$ x = x) we get I $*$ I = I $\land$ I $*$ I = I, which supposedly completes the proof.

I don't understand how one goes from x $*$ x$^-$$^1$ = I $\land$ x$^-$$^1$ $*$ x = I to I $*$ I = I $\land$ I $*$ I = I using the definition of x$^-$$^1$ described above, and I don't understand how I $\land$ I $*$ I = I is the solution to the proof?

Comment: One does not "go from x $*$ x$^-$$^1$ = I $\land$ x$^-$$^1$ $*$ x = I to I $*$ I = I $\land$ I $*$ I = I using the definition of x$^-$$^1$ described above", rather, one notes that I $*$ I = I by definition of I and one deduces from this single fact that I$^-$$^1$ = I.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the definition of a group $V$ :  For each $x\in V$ there is exactly one $y\in V$ , called the inverse of $x$, for which $x y=y x=I$. What is the definition of $x^{-1}$ ? It's the inverse of $x$. So with $x=I$ and $y=I$, what do we have for $x y$ and $y x$?